# IBM Edge components executor giving error while running it

Tags: websphere

I have installed IBM Edge components for ipv4 dispatcher on windows 7, it gets successfully installed but when I am trying to start executor it is giving me below  error.

Error: kernel was not loaded (FAILURE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LB for ipv4 is not supported on Windows 7. Assuming you are using version 8.5.5, Windows 2008 is the only supported release for LB for ipv4.

By the way, LB for ipv4 is a dead component and you probably don't want to be using it on a new install. It is going out of support forever Sept of this year. Try using LB for ipv4 and ipv6 instead.

Comment: LB for ipv4 and ipv6 is this supported on windows 7?

Comment: Both load balancers support server grade releases of Windows and Windows 7 is not offered as a server solution so you will probably encounter performance issues but LB for ipv4 and ipv6 will work on Windows 7.  If you are working towards a production grade LB, I would recommend LB for ipv4 and ipv6 on Linux.